# PhoneGap unable to Remove File

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to remove a file from an SD card using phonegap build but I can't. I think my code have some problem, Its not getting entered into the gotRemoveFileEntry function. Whats the problem?

Here is my code:

```
function removefile(){
fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: false, exclusive: false}, gotRemoveFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotRemoveFileEntry(fileEntry){
console.log(fileEntry);
fileEntry.remove(success, fail);
}

function success(entry) {
console.log("Removal succeeded");
}

function fail(error) {
console.log("Error removing file: " + error.code);
}
```

Please anybody help me to remove a created file.

I am using Cordova 2.5.0.